# Replace multiple occurrencies of a substring with a single occurrence of it

Tags: java, replace

I am trying to perform a cleaning of a HTML text, and I want to replace multiple occurrencies of `&nbsp;` with a single occurrence of it.

So, for example:

```
<o:p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</o:p></b></p>
```

should become

```
<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></b></p>
```

despite the number of `&nbsp;`s, that could vary.

I could use a `replace()` in a loop, repeating until the result varies. But I think there could exist a one-linear or at least a smarter method.

Comment: Like `.replaceAll("(&nbsp;)+", "&nbsp;")`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thank you, just realized how silly my question was. If you post it as answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String has a second method to replace substrings besides the standard `replace` that takes a regular expression as an argument called `replaceAll`. (*)

With that method you can easily do it with a simply

```
 .replaceAll("(&nbsp;)+", "&nbsp;")
```

(*) That those 2 method are really badly named and often confuse beginners is a very well known weakness of java/the String class.